# Does a uint64 take 8 bytes storage?

Tags: go

Official document says uint64 is an unsigned integer of 64-bits, does that mean any uint64 number should take 8 bytes storage, no matter how small or how large it is?

Edit:

Thanks for everyone's answer!

I raised the doubt when I noticed that `binary.PutUvarint` consumes up to 10 bytes to store a large `uint64`, despite that maximum `uint64` should only take 8 bytes.

I then found answer to my doubt in the source code of Golang lib:

```
Design note:
// At most 10 bytes are needed for 64-bit values. The encoding could
// be more dense: a full 64-bit value needs an extra byte just to hold bit 63.
// Instead, the msb of the previous byte could be used to hold bit 63 since we
// know there can't be more than 64 bits. This is a trivial improvement and
// would reduce the maximum encoding length to 9 bytes. However, it breaks the
// invariant that the msb is always the "continuation bit" and thus makes the
// format incompatible with a varint encoding for larger numbers (say 128-bit).
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to http://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees:

```
type                                 size in bytes

byte, uint8, int8                     1
uint16, int16                         2
uint32, int32, float32                4
uint64, int64, float64, complex64     8
complex128                           16
```

So, yes, uint64 will *always* take 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: yes, a 64-bit fixed size integer type will always take 8 bytes. It would be an unusual language where that isn't the case.

There are languages/platforms which support variable-length numeric types where the storage in memory *does* depend on the value, but you wouldn't then specify the number of bits in the type in such a simple way, as that can vary.

Answer (score 1):

> The Go Programming Language Specification
>
> [Numeric types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> A numeric type represents sets of integer or floating-point values.
>   The predeclared architecture-independent numeric types are:
>
> ```
> uint64      the set of all unsigned 64-bit integers (0 to 18446744073709551615)
> ```

Yes, exactly 64 bits or 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember the simple rule, the variable type is usually optimized to fit certain memory space and the minimum memory space is 1 bit(s). And 8 bit(s) = 1 byte(s):

Therefore 64bit(s) = 8 byte(s)